# issue with Add_month in oracle , I need to generate billing cycle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a requirement to generate to Billing cycle date, ex

- if My input is 27th March then my next cycle starts from 27 april.
- If input is 10th Jan then next cycle should start from 10th Feb.

I am using Oracle Add_Month(i/p Date, 1). This add a new month and give me same date for next month, working fine for above mentioned dates.

But there is one corner case when my Input date is 28th Feb, 2018 and If I do select ADD_MONTHS(date '2018-02-28', 1) from dual then output is 31st March,2018.

I am expecting the outcome should be 28thMarch. Any poosible solution for this corner case.

Comment: And if your input is 30th Jan... what should be the output?

Comment: Hi D le, this is also a corner case , but my requirement is not allowing startdate to be 29,30, 31.  Any other day can be possible .

Answer (score 2):

A little bit of calculation might help.

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select date '2020-03-27' from dual union all
  3     select date '2020-01-10' from dual union all
  4     select date '2018-02-27' from dual union all
  5     select date '2018-02-28' from dual
  6    )
  7  select col,
  8    least(add_months(col, 1),
  9          add_months(trunc(col, 'mm'), 1) + (col - trunc(col, 'mm'))
 10         ) result
 11  from test
 12  order by col;

COL        RESULT
---------- ----------
27.02.2018 27.03.2018
28.02.2018 28.03.2018
10.01.2020 10.02.2020
27.03.2020 27.04.2020

SQL>
```

Comment: Hi @LittleFoot, this logic is working fine , can you help in adding one more check. I need to groupBy over Salary for the Cycle. Ex : Date and Salary column. Over the given for the given dates it returns sum of salary for the calculated cycles between given start and end date.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand that. Please, edit the original question you posted and provide sample data and desired output.

Comment: I have two columns in My DB : Date and Salary , For given Input date range I need to sum salary and display for the generated cycle. Ex if input date range is from 28-Feb-2018 to 9th April 2018. Output would be :  
 28-Feb-18 Sum(salary  in range 28-Feb to 27March)
 28-Mar-18 Sum(Salary in range 28-mar to remaing days)

Comment: @Neeraj I would suggest to post a separate question or edit your question with additional details with example.

Comment: @Atif sure will do

Answer (score 0):

```
select to_date('28-FEB-2020', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 
ADD_MONTHS( to_date('28-FEB-2020', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 1) from dual;
```

[image]

```
select to_date('28-FEB-2018', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 
ADD_MONTHS( to_date('28-FEB-2018', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 1) from dual;
```

Above query will give you 31st March because, 28th FEB is the last day of the month on 2018 and since you are using ADD_MONTHS function, it is considering the last day of each month. Execute below query, you will understand easily,

```
select to_date('28-FEB-2018', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 
ADD_MONTHS( to_date('28-FEB-2018', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 1) from dual;
```

Comment: Hi Jim, If i run this query : select ADD_MONTHS(date '2018-02-28', 1) from dual , o/p is 31st March. Can you please elaborate what this to_date internally does in your case

Comment: Hi @Neeraj, provided you the snipping of the result as well. Can you say which version of the database are you using?

Comment: Jim , I checked your query again, there is issue in Year you are passing. Kindly put date as 28th-Feb-2018. Then you will get the outcome as 31st March 2018

Comment: Provided you he detailed description in the answer. Let me know if you could not understand

Comment: Jim, I knew this beahvior of Add_month, that's why corner case is failing and was asking for the answer  how to handle that particular Failing case

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code and accordingly add conditions for 29th Feb as well if you want.

```
select 
case when extract( day from last_day(to_date('28-FEB-2020', 'DD-MON-YYYY'))) =  extract( day from to_date('28-FEB-2020', 'DD-MON-YYYY')) 
        then decode(extract( day from last_day(to_date('28-FEB-2020', 'DD-MON-YYYY'))), 28, to_date('28-FEB-2020', 'DD-MON-YYYY') + 28,ADD_MONTHS( to_date('28-FEB-2020', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 1) ) 
        else ADD_MONTHS( to_date('28-FEB-2020', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 1) end as result
from dual;
```