# I have a calendar Table and I need to display only 15th and 30th for every month

Tags: sql, database, oracle, date, where-clause

Here is the code I am using to display the last date of the month

```
SELECT * FROM Calendar_table 
WHERE date in (SELECT MAX(date) from Calendar_table
ORDER BY YEAR, 
         DATE);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `to_char()` to extract the day of the month from the date, and use it for filtering:

```
select *
from calendar_table
where to_char(dt, 'dd') in ('15', '30')
```

This assumes that the calendar date is stored in column `dt`.

You can also use `extract()`:

```
select *
from calendar_table
where extract(day from dt) in (15, 30)
```

On the other hand, if you want the 15th of the month and the last day of the month, then:

```
select *
from calendar_table
where extract(day from dt) = 15 or last_day(dt) = dt
```

Comment: But if we use this logic for February it wont pick the last date.

Comment: @GiriRaja: you said you wanted the 30th of the month, not the last day of the month, hence my answer. See my updated answer for an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

Few days back I have answered a question related to last day handling may be you can use it for the same:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63134303/10908274